# Convert decimal to hex in assembly

Tags: assembly, hex, type-conversion

Can someone explain to me decimal to hex conversion algorithm in assembly?I have a decimal value in a variable and I should print it as a hex value.Print should look like this: 34AC6 .

Comment: Very unpleasantly.  You'll have to determine the value of the decimal string ("100"), then make a new string that is the same value in hex ("0x64").  It's the same algorithm that you use to do the conversion in your head; it's just a bit more complicated since you have to deal with ASCII encoding on top of things.

Comment: This looks to be a please-answer-my-homework-question question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that this is a homework, here's a couple of hints:

- The value in the variable is *not* in decimal, hex, or any other system: it is in whatever system that your hardware supports (most likely, it is binary).
- To convert a value to hex, you need to separate out 4-bit chunks by shifting right and masking with `0x0F`, and indexing into an array of hexadecimal digits.