# Using EMU8086, is there a direct way to print a variable's hex value?

Tags: assembly, x86

I'm using EMU8086 on a Windows 7 HP x64, Intel i3-2330m PC.

I have spent about two weeks researching and tinkering with this Assembly language program in an effort to print the hex value of an integer entered by the user. I have found nothing about directly printing a value from a memory location. I can, if necessary, write the code to do the string conversion to hex. However, I am attempting to avoid the extra lines of code to do this. (I think that is called optimizing.)

My research has lead me to a [comment on this site by Corbin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10777551/convert-decimal-to-hex-in-assembly) which says:

> Very unpleasantly. You'll have to determine the value of the decimal
>   string ("100"), then make a new string that is the same value in hex
>   ("0x64"). It's the same algorithm that you use to do the conversion in
>   your head; it's just a bit more complicated since you have to deal
>   with ASCII encoding on top of things.

None of this has directed me to a manner in which I desire to perform the task.

I have written and tested the code incrementally, receiving the desired results. By watching the variable and viewing the CX register, I can confirm that their values are the values I want to print.

I am including my code here. It is probably ugly and is definitely over-commented. The commenting is for my benefit to help me learn/remember what I have done as I progress.

```
 ; program name: convert_decimal_to_hex
 ; by W K
 ; August, 2015
 ; This program accepts an integer between 1 and 10000 and
 ; prints the hexadecimal value to the console
 ;
 ;
 #MAKE_COM# ;instruct compiler to make COM file
 include emu8086.inc    ;use include file for macros
 ORG 100h   ;directive for COM program, set offset to 100h
 ;
 MOV DX, offset msg1    ;moves value of msg1 to the data register
 ;                       
 MOV AH, 9  ;moves the value 9 to the high accumulator register
            ;to be used with the interrupt
 INT 21h    ;invokes interrupt to print string to DOS window
 ;
 MOV DX,13  ;these lines
  MOV AH,2  ;create a
  INT 21h   ;newline
  MOV DX,10 ;and
  MOV AH,2  ;move the cursor
  INT 21h   ;to the newline
 ;
 CALL SCAN_NUM  ;calls macro to scan numeric keyboard input
                ;error catching is included in macro
                ;number is stored in CX 
  MOV DX,13 ;these lines
  MOV AH,2  ;create a
  INT 21h   ;newline
  MOV DX,10 ;and
  MOV AH,2  ;move the cursor
  INT 21h   ;to the newline
 ;  
 MOV DX, offset msg2    ;moves value of msg2 to the data register
 MOV AX, CX ;copies scanned number to AX to be printed
            ;as part of message
 ;MOV AH, 9  ;moves the value 9 to the high accumulator register
             ;to be used with the interrupt
 ;INT 21h    ;invokes interrupt to print string to DOS window 


 CALL PRINT_NUM_UNS  ;prints hexadecimal value at end of msg2
 MOV CONVERTEDNUMBER, CX
 ;                       
 MOV AH, 9  ;moves the value 9 to the high accumulator register
            ;to be used with the interrupt
 INT 21h    ;invokes interrupt to print string to DOS window
 ;
 MOV AX, 0  ;wait for any key
 INT 16h    ;prevents window from closing immediately
 ;
 msg1 db "Type an integer between 1 and 10000, and press enter. $"    
    ;declare string variable 
 msg2 db " in hexadecimal is: $" 
 ;
 DEFINE_SCAN_NUM    ;defines macro from include file
                    ;gets multidigit signed number from keyboard
 DEFINE_PRINT_NUM_UNS   ;defines macro from include file
                        ;prints unsigned number in AX
 ;                                                   
 CONVERTEDNUMBER DW 0   ;declare variable
 ;
 RET    ;return to operating system
 END    ;directive to stop compiler
```

Is there a procedure to directly print the variable value or CX register value without writing the lines of code to convert the string value input by the user? Any references to articles, code examples, or other helpful advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no standard MS-DOS or BIOS service for converting a decimal number stored in a string to a hexadecimal number stored in a string. It's possible that EMU8086 has some sort of extension for this, but I doubt it. If you want this sort of functionality I suggest learning a higher level language like C or Python. If your example code isn't working you'll need to post another question that includes all necessary code to reproduce the problem before anyone can help you find and fix the bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOS only provides you with interrupts to write *characters* to the standard output (`INT 21H / AH=2` for a single character, and `INT 21H / AH=9` for a `$`-terminated string of characters).

So you *will* have to convert any number you want to print into a string first, in whatever base you wish to display the number in. Fortunately that's very easy to do. Below is an example of how one could print 32-bit hexadecimal numbers (I'll leave it as an exercise to you to strip the leading zeroes):

```
; Input:
; EAX = value to print
;
print_hex:
    mov cx,8        ; print 8 hex digits (= 32 bits)
    .print_digit:
        rol eax,4   ; move the currently left-most digit into the least significant 4 bits
        mov dl,al
        and dl,0xF  ; isolate the hex digit we want to print
        add dl,'0'  ; and convert it into a character..
        cmp dl,'9'  ; ...
        jbe .ok     ; ...
        add dl,7    ; ... (for 'A'..'F')
    .ok:            ; ...
        push eax    ; save EAX on the stack temporarily
        mov ah,2    ; INT 21H / AH=2: write character to stdout
        int 0x21
        pop eax     ; restore EAX
        loop .print_digit
        ret
```

Printing numbers in base 10 or base 2 is not that much different. It's just that when we deal with bases that are powers of two (like 16 or 2), we can use shifts (or rotates in my code) and ANDs rather than division and remainders.

Comment: Because I am confined to assembly language for this exercise, and I am using EMU8086 (16-bit emulator), it will take a little effort to make this happen. That poses no problem to me because of the learning experience I will gain. I had thought that I had overlooked something in the effort to print the values directly.

The code provided will be helpful in writing the appropriate 16-bit code.

Comment: The code in my answer is valid 16-bit code. Though it might require an 80286 or 80386 to run, because of the use of `EAX`. The simple fix would be to change all occurrences of `EAX` to `AX` (though this would limit you to printing 16-bit values).

Comment: It would probably be better to push/pop `ebx` around the whole function, instead of `push`/`pop` of eax inside the loop.

Comment: Can you reuse this code to print more than one variable? Im trying to print var1 and after that print var2 but im having some problems there @Michael

Comment: @lLauriix I don't see why that wouldn't work. But if you wanted to insert some whitespace between two numbers then you'd have to do so yourself, because this function won't do it.

Comment: @Michael Maybe I'm just not implementing it correctly, may I tag you in a new question?

Comment: @Michael https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71587840/how-do-i-print-multiple-variables-in-assembly-x86 I would appreciate your help with this!